# jackson serializer: custom serializer based on a different field

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

i have a field of list that i want to serialize.
I also want to serialize the max of the  or the max i've seen so far whenever the class is serialized.

```
class A {
private List<int> list;
private int max; //Math.Max(max, Collections.max(list));}
```

I think i need to use @JsonSerialize annotation, but the custom serializer i specify here would either take list or max, not both. 
Is it possible to add serializer for max field that uses data from list field?

Answer (score 0):

The list is `private` in your class, so you completely control how elements are added to it.  I.e., nothing can be added to the list without some code in your class performing the operation.

Therefore, whatever code adds (and deletes, if you do that) elements should just update the `max` value as part of its operation.  Then when serializing use the standard serializers on both the list and the `max`.

If for some reason you expose the list, for example by having a method that returns a reference to the list, then you should subclass `List<whatever>` and override the `add()` method to keep track of the max.

Comment: i was thinking about that, but i was curious if there is more 'mistake-proof' way of doing this by using custom serializer. I do leak the list to outside of the class for callers to manipulate. the code has been this way for a few years and i don't want to go and change all of them

Comment: Simply create a nested class `private static class ListWithMax extends ArrayList<Integer>` and use that internally while still returning `List<Integer>`

Comment: hm.. wouldn't that break deserialization of old data?

Comment: Probably. You'd have to do some experimentation before settling on an approach, and you didn't share all the details in your question.  Leaking a reference to a private member was the critical error.  You might have to convert all the existing serialized data to the new format.